# Pipeline to use artifacts from 2 projects associated by the same git branch name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, jenkins-blueocean

the company where I work for is evaluating jenkins 2.71, in particular the **pipeline** and **blue ocean** plugins. We already tested also [GoCD](https://docs.gocd.org/current/) and we need, as in **GoCD**, a way for a pipeline to automatically fetch the artifacts from 2 other pipelines (taking the last successful result of each one of them), here our case.

We have these initial pipelines (build & run tests), which reflect 2 projects:

- **frontend**, ~ 15 minutes
- **backend**, ~10 minutes

I created a pipeline called **configure** (~1 minute), with e.g. a parameter called *customer-name*, which takes backend and frontend files and puts them together, then applies specific customer specific configurations and customizations and produces deployable artifacts. Instead of "customer-name" I could also parallelize this job to create all the artifacts for each customer at once, separated in different directories.

The next pipeline would be to deploy them on different test servers separated for each customer. This could be also part of the same **configure** pipeline, we still have to see how to put things together in jenkins...

Ideally, I need **configure** pipeline to be **triggered automatically (or also on demand) after each frontend or backend success** and take as input the last successful artifacts from these 2 pipelines, but not just having the last successful build, we need as **dependency the git branch name**.

E.g. we have:

backend branches:

- master
- release/2017.2

frontend braches:

- master
- release/2017.2

In the pipeline editor, I found a **Build Triggers** option and set it as follows: **Build after other projects are built** > *Projects to watch*: frontend, backend > Check *Trigger only if build is stable* or better in my test environment full of failures *Trigger even if the build is unstable*.

Searching further, I found [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

But now the big question, **how to fetch the last successful artifacts from these pipelines with the same git branch name**?

Because we don't want to mix e.g. a backend build of "release/2017.2" with frontend "master", it has to find as the last successful build having the same relationship or parameter or whatever you wanna call it, in our case the association is the git branch name.

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

The copy artifact plugin seems to work in a freestyle project. Would it work in a pipeline? That's also a concern...

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this can be done.  I will try to provide a more detailed answer when I have more time, but take a look at the `copyArtifact` function.  Also, there's a Pipeline Syntax link on the left side navigation bar when you are on a Pipeline project (you might have to be at the configuration page already, I can't remember off hand) that details how to do a lot of these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Copy Artifact plugin does work in both freestyle and pipeline projects; pipeline uses the `copyArtifact` function that I referenced in my comment.  Note that if you go to the Pipeline Syntax link, it's kind of hidden: you have to first select `"step: General Build Step"` from the drop-down, then it will give you the Copy Artifact pipeline command builder.

I'm going to assume that your `frontend` and `backend` projects are built as multi-branch pipelines, as that would probably be easiest to maintain so that you don't have to keep creating new projects for every release.  You can reference these projects from other projects by referencing `<project name>/<branch name>` (sometimes I've had to replace the `/` with `%2f` instead, I think mostly on freestyle projects).  You could then set up your `configure` project as a parameterized build (either pipeline or freestyle), say with a string parameter of `PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME`.  Then put in the following in your frontend/backend project pipeline scripts to trigger a build of your `configure` project

`build job: 'configure', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME', value: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}]]`

Then you should just be able to make your `configure` project reference the `frontend/%PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME%` and `backend/%PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME%` (or `${env.PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME}` in a pipeline script) when copying the artifacts.

Also, is there a particular reason why you're evaluating specifically Jenkins 2.7?  2.7 is a year old now, and there have been a few new LTS releases since then.  I'd recommend staying reasonably up-to-date unless you know there's a specific reason you want 2.7.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try tomorrow at work! About jenkins version, I confused it, I'm used to SEMVER, so I thought it was 2.7.0, but it was **2.70**, I downloaded it one week ago, already updated to 2.71 today :) I also edited the question to avoid confusion... and yes, we will probably put a Jenkins file in the frontend and one in the backend repo.

Comment: Your answer really helped me a lot, THANK YOU. I just had to fight a bit with escaping/encoding problems and variable names... e.g. I had to use `value: env.BRANCH_NAME` (instead of *${env.BRANCH_NAME}*, no *${}*).

Also I had to create an extra variable: `def branchname = "${PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME}".replace("/", "%2f")` because it was not passed properly by the upstream pipeline. It seems a known issue...

Also in the copyArtifact step, I had to use: `projectName: "frontend/${branchname}"` (instead of *frontend/%PROJECT_BRANCH_NAME%* - *%%* don't work)

Comment: Kdawg: I have a new question related to this setup, maybe you can help me there too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377411/jenkins-copyartifact