# Jenkins Copy Artifact unable to find folder/multiProjectPipeline/branchWithSlash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have Jenkins LTS 2.60.2 on Windows Server 2016 and using these plugins:

- Folders plugin (6.1.0)
- [Copy Artifact](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin (1.38.1)
- Pipeline plugin (2.5) + all dependent pipeline sub-plugins
- Various other dependent plugins...

See [Pipeline to use artifacts from 2 projects associated by the same git branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282440/pipeline-to-use-artifacts-from-2-projects-associated-by-the-same-git-branch-name) for more details about my setup, but to sum it up I have these items:

- playground (a folder created with the Folders plugin to group all these following items)
- frontend (multibranch pipeline)
- backend (multibranch pipeline)
- configure (pipeline with a parameter called BRANCH_NAME)

The frontend and backend **git repos**, both have a branch called **master** and one called **release/2017.2**.

The idea is to call the *configure* pipeline automatically after each successful build, passing the git branch name. Automatically triggering the *configure* pipeline works.

What doesn't work and I need your help to fix, is the step inside the *configure* pipeline to copy the artifacts from a multibranchPipeline/specificBranch.

If for the BRANCH_NAME parameter (or the upstream pipeline) is *master* it works. If BRANCH_NAME is: *release/2017.2* I get this error:

> ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy:
>   playground/frontend/release%2f2017.2 This may be due to incorrect project
>   name or permission settings; see help for project name in job
>   configuration. Finished: FAILURE

The **configure pipeline** looks like this:

```
node {
  stage('Prepare') {
      def projectname = "playground/frontend/" + "${BRANCH_NAME}".replace("/", "%2f")
      step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: "${projectname}", selector: [$class: 'StatusBuildSelector', stable: false]])
  }
  stage('Archive') {
      archiveArtifacts '**'
  }
}
```

As you can see I already replace / with %2f (it's needed).

If I don't use the "playground" folder (all my pipelines as is, not inside a folder item), it works. If I use the folder and use the master branch, it works. It doesn't work if I use the folder and a branch name like 2017.2. What am I doing wrong? Can you help making it work? Of well if it's a bug (I searched in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org and found some bugs where a similar setup with folder doesn't work, but they have been fixed... so I really wonder...) in the copy artifact plugin, please file the bug and share the link here, so we can all monitor its progress...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The *configure* pipeline was failing to find a branch with a slash because the encoding was incorrect.

So, in my question, in the *configure* pipeline:

this (replace `/` with `%2f`) is wrong and generates the **error**:

```
def projectname = "playground/frontend/" + "${BRANCH_NAME}".replace("/", "%2f")
```

this is the proper way to encode the slash, and it **works**:

```
def projectname = "playground/frontend/" +  URLEncoder.encode("${BRANCH_NAME}", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")
```

Credits to: http://www.pipegrep.se/copy-artifacts-from-jenkins-pipeline-jobs.html

**UPDATE**: actually, I investigated a bit further and added `echo "${projectname}"` just before `step`, with the previous and fixed projectname, and I noticed that the difference was `%2f` **lowercase**.

**Uppercase**, like this: `%2F` works:

```
def projectname = "playground/frontend/" + "${BRANCH_NAME}".replace("/", "%2F")
```

So, the fixed *configure* pipeline looks like this (I kept my replace function, which was enough for my case):

```
node {
  stage('Prepare') {
      def projectname = "playground/frontend/" + "${BRANCH_NAME}".replace("/", "%2F")
      step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: "${projectname}", selector: [$class: 'StatusBuildSelector', stable: false]])
  }
  stage('Archive') {
      archiveArtifacts '**'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/kdawg14/frontend) to try and recreate what you were seeing, and I was able to do so, after a fashion, except that the build that I was having trouble on was `master` instead of `release/2017.2`.  Eventually, I realized that I was doing the `build job` incorrectly from the `frontend` project, and it was giving me the same error as you because I hadn't ever completed a successful build of the `frontend/master` branch (I had completed a successful build of the `release/2017.2` branch because I didn't have it triggering the `configure` build initially, so it didn't give me the same error once I did configure it to trigger the `configure` build).

What worked was changing the `build job` in the `frontend` `Jenkinsfile` to this:

`build job: 'playground/configure', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH_NAME', value: env.BRANCH_NAME]], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false`

Adding in the `quietPeriod` gives a couple seconds of quiet time between completing the previous job (I'm not certain that this is critical, but it seems like it might be a nice fail-safe, to try and make sure there's enough time for the build to complete), but the important part is the `wait: false`, which instructs Jenkins that this build shouldn't wait for the triggered build to complete.  Once I changed that, the `frontend/master` branch completed successfully, and the `configure` build that it triggered also completed successfully.

Hopefully this helps.  I was able to get both my `master` and `release/2017.2` branches to build properly, so I don't believe there's any intrinsic problem with the `/` in the project name.  You can see my simple `Jenkinsfile`s in the referenced repo, and I used the same pipeline script as you posted in your question.

Comment: It's also possible that I was getting a slightly different error and that this won't solve your problem.  Still, it does show that what you're trying to do is doable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kdawg, maybe I didn't specify but the problem is in the *configure* job. I run successfully the *frontend* job (the last part calling *configure* I wrapped in a try and catch so even if it fails, the build is marked as successful), then I run the configure job again, by specifying the parameter "release/2017.2" that's where the error shows. Also in my setup I'm not using github but gerrit for the git repository. Maybe on github it works, but on other git servers it doesn't?

Comment: Kdawg, *quietPeriod* and *wait* help to speed up the build and avoid to use *try/catch*, but the *configure* pipeline always fails with this error:
`ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: playground/frontend/release%2f2017.2
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: @firepol I just tried again and what worked before didn't work for me this time, and I started getting the same error as you were seeing, which was kind of confusing.  However, I just changed the `%2f` to `%2F` and it worked.  And I see from your update that you found it too :)